# Objective-C : iphone programming 'UITextField while editing method'

Tags: uialertview, textfield

I got a UITextField and I want to send a UIAlertView if the user enter nothing in the UITextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First capture the input:

```
NSString *text = myTextField.text;
```

Then test for null string and present alertview:

```
if (title == [NSNull null] || title.length == 0 ) {

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:button1 otherButtonTitles:button2, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: thx for response but i got a warning : Comparison of distinct objective-c struct NSNull and struct NSString lacks a cast

Comment: you can avoid the warning by using the somewhat more verbose:

if ([[NSNull null] isEqual:text] || title.length == 0)